# SetWindowsHookEx to determine when a window is deactivated

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I have a global `WH_CBT` 32bit hook that I am using to determine when a window is about to be activated using `HCBT_ACTIVATE`.

How can I determine when the window is about to be deactivated?
There is the `CBTACTIVATESTRUCT` which has `hWndActive`, but that is sometimes `0x0`and it wont work when switching to a 64bit window.

There is no `HCBT_DEACTIVATE`.

Comment: What happens when you use a 64 bit hook?

Comment: The window I'm interested in is 32 bit, so I am installing a hook in a 32 bit dll from a 32 bit exe. I don't really want to have to spawn a 64 bit exe to install a 64 bit hook.

Comment: Sometimes you have to use an approach that works rather than what suits

Comment: A CBT hook does not tell you when a window is being deactivated (neither does `SetWinEventHook()`, it seems). Try using a message hook instead and look for [`WM_ACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate) window messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As@Remy Lebeau mentioned, you can use `WM_ACTIVATE` message. This message is sent both when the window is activated or deactivated.
Set a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook to capture the deactivated message, it will get the messages before the system sends them to the destination window procedure.
For more detail:

Use a function in a DLL for a non-local hook:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevinstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    HWND hwnd;
    //...

    DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("..\\Debug\\ProcHookDLL.dll"));
    void (*AttachHookProc)(DWORD);
    AttachHookProc = (void (*)(DWORD)) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "AttachHook");
    AttachHookProc(threadID);

    MSG msg = {};

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    //...
};
```

Here is the code for the DLL:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HMODULE thisModule;
HHOOK hook;
LRESULT CALLBACK LaunchListener(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

#ifdef __cplusplus      // If used by C++ code, 
    extern "C" {        // we need to export the C interface
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) void AttachHook(DWORD threadID) {
        hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, LaunchListener, thisModule, threadID);
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
    LRESULT CALLBACK LaunchListener(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        // process event here
        if (nCode >= 0) {
            CWPSTRUCT* cwp = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
            if (cwp->message == WM_ACTIVATE) {
                if (LOWORD(cwp->wParam) == WA_INACTIVE)
                {
                    //the window being deactivated
                }
                else
                {
                    //the window being activated
                }
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult to find the correct hook. I tried `WH_CBT` and `WH_GETMESSAGE`. It was the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook I needed. Thanks.